# XML formatting in SQL Server xml path

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to get a particular XML format by querying SQL Server.

My nested query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    @xml = (SELECT 
                AdmissionID AS "@encounter_number",
                'NDIS' AS organisation_code,
                'NDIS' AS encounter_type,
                (SELECT 'true' as "@delete",
                    (SELECT 'NDIS' AS class_type, AdmissionDate AS start_date_time 
                     FOR XML PATH ('financial_class'), TYPE) 
                 FOR XML PATH('financial_classes'), TYPE),
                (SELECT URNumber AS 'payor/@entity_number', 'Patient' AS slot, CONVERT (varchar(10), AdmissionDate, 126) AS start_date 
                 FOR XML PATH('payor'), ROOT ('payors'), ELEMENTS, TYPE),
                URNumber AS "recipient/@entity_number",
                'H' AS referral_source,
                'H' AS separation_status,
                AdmissionDate AS start_date_time
            FROM 
                HMS
            FOR XML PATH('encounter'), ROOT ('pbrc'), TYPE)
```

which returns this output:

```
<pbrc>
  <encounter encounter_number="525241">
    <organisation_code>NDIS</organisation_code>
    <encounter_type>NDIS</encounter_type>
    <financial_classes delete="true">
      <financial_class>
        <class_type>NDIS</class_type>
        <start_date_time>2018-06-26T00:00:00</start_date_time>
      </financial_class>
    </financial_classes>
    <payors>
      <payor>
        <payor entity_number="4208151" />
        <slot>Patient</slot>
        <start_date>2018-06-26</start_date>
      </payor>
    </payors>
    <recipient entity_number="4208151" />
    <referral_source>H</referral_source>
    <separation_status>H</separation_status>
    <start_date_time>2018-06-26T00:00:00</start_date_time>
  </encounter>
</pbrc>
```

But I am trying to achieve the following format for payor with proper payor closing tag and not the short form,

```
-<payors>
 -<payor>
 <payor entity_number="8195991"> </payor>

 <slot>Patient</slot>

 <start_date>2019-06-01</start_date>

 </payor>

</payors>
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a comment, but I shifted it into the answer:

> Are you aware of the fact, that - semantically - there's no difference
>   between `<SomeElement />` and `<SomeElement></SomeElement>`? Is the
>   `blank` between `<payor>` and `</payor>` important? In fact, it is up
>   to the presenting engine, how this will be looking. The same XML might
>   appear in different shape depeding on the viewer...

You can try something along this:

```
DECLARE @mockPayor TABLE(enitityNumber INT,slot VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockPayor VALUES(123,'slot123')
```

--This will return the *self-closed* payor element

```
SELECT p.enitityNumber AS [payor/@entityNumber]
      ,p.slot
FROM @mockPayor p
FOR XML PATH('payor')
```

The result

```
<payor>
  <payor entityNumber="123" />
  <slot>slot123</slot>
</payor>
```

And this will return the *proper payor closing tag*:

```
SELECT p.enitityNumber AS [payor/@entityNumber]
      ,' ' AS [payor]
      ,p.slot
FROM @mockPayor p
FOR XML PATH('payor');
```

The result

```
<payor>
  <payor entityNumber="123"> </payor>
  <slot>slot123</slot>
</payor>
```

Some background:

The engine works this down and thinks:

- Okay, there is an entityNumber attribute living within a payor element. Well I have to open the payor element and insert the entitiyNumber.
- Now there is a slot element. So I have to close the payor **without any content** and open the slot element.

In the second statement the engine thinks:

- Same as above
- Now there is some content to be placed **into** the payor element
- Same as above, but replace the bold part with **after the content**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated. Yes I am aware that semantically there is no difference. But I am creating this xml for a 'dumb' Invoice software who needs that particular format.